# Centered Titles with font awesome circle in Bootstrap Responsive design

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

I am trying to accomplish the following (see image):
[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h1>5 BENEFITS FOR $5</h1>  
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>BENEFIT NAME</h2>
<p>A very brief but captivating description of the benefit.</p>
</div><!-- col -->

<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>BENEFIT NAME</h2>
<p>We’re just getting started - as our club grows, so will the benefits!</p>
</div><!-- col -->
</div> <!--row-->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>BENEFIT NAME</h2>
<p>A very brief but captivating description of the benefit.</p>
</div><!-- col -->

<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>BENEFIT NAME</h2>
<p>We’re just getting started - as our club grows, so will the benefits!</p>
</div><!-- col -->
</div> <!--row-->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>BENEFIT NAME</h2>
<p>A very brief but captivating description of the benefit.</p>
</div><!-- col -->

<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>AND MORE</h2>
<p>We’re just getting started - as our club grows, so will the benefits!</p>
</div><!-- col -->
</div> <!--row-->

</div> <!--container-->


#front-page-2 h2 {
  position: relative; /* Helps us control overlap */
  padding-left: 80px; /* Creates space for the Phone Icon */
  padding-top:15px;
  }

#front-page-2 h2:after {
  content: '\f111';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
  top: 3px; /* Adjust as needed */
  }
```

I am using Bootstrap 4, with 3 rows and two columns of col-sm-6 on each row. I need the circles to line up even. Currently, when a column title changes in length, for example "AND MORE", the circle does not lineup with the others. I also want that each col-sm-6 to be centered in the container, so it centers with the main header 5 Benefits for $5 (see image below). I would also like to use font awesome with the h2 title .

Thanks, Jules

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Code added. Note the main issue is when i try to center everything, can't get the circles to lineup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution may be using `position:absolute` for icons.`<h2>` is a block element so you can easily position icons on the left side. The position of the circle does not depend on the text lenght.

```css
h2{position:relative;text-align:center}
.fa-circle{position:absolute;left:0;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%)}

/*DEMO PURPOSE*/
h2{border:1px red solid;padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/js/all.js"></script>

<h2><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<h2><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>Dolor sit Amet</h2>
<h2><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>Some text</h2>
```